# Curve radius in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numeric, calculus

I have this curve and I would like to compute the radius and the center of the curve below:
 [image]

The data for this curve https://pastebin.com/FZTi3bAf

My code so far:

```
poly = np.polyfit(df['x'], df['y'],2)
p = np.poly1d(poly)
```

I need to have new point (x, y) as input in this problem.

Comment: What is the point w.r.t which you wish to calculate the radius? Also, since the curve is not an arc(?), the radius will probably be variable. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: I need to find the points in the frenet frame. And for start I need to find this radius even if it’s a variable. The goal of this problem is to read new point (x,y) and convert for frenet frame.

Comment: What’s the actual problem you’re facing - is it how to calculate a “radius” for all the points?

Comment: Yes, to calculate the radius for this trajectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot the line from 2 edge points and calculate the distance from the middle of this line to curve (`dh`). Then if `dl` is the distance between edge points you can write `(dl/2)^2 = (2R - dh) * dh` and get `R` from this equation.

```
a = df.to_numpy()
x_middle = (a[0, 0] + a[-1, 0]) / 2
y_middle = (a[0, 1] + a[-1, 1]) / 2
dx = a[-1, 0] - a[0, 0]
dy = a[0, 1] - a[-1, 1]
dl = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
cos = dx / dl
sin = dy / dl
dh = cos * (np.interp(x_middle, a[:, 0], a[:, 1]) - y_middle)
R = dl ** 2 / 8 / dh + dh / 2
x0 = x_middle - (R - dh) * sin
y0 = y_middle - (R - dh) * cos


plt.scatter(a[:, 0], a[:, 1])
circle = plt.Circle((x0, y0), R, fill=False)
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Since the radius will obviously be variable for a non-circular curve, all it boils down to is calculating the distances of all the points from a *chosen* centre point.
If this centre point is your origin, distances are just `sqrt(x**2 + y**2)` where `x, y` is a particular coordinate in your dataset. If the centre is at some point `x0, y0`, then this becomes `sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2)`.

All of these can be very conveniently achieved by considering the points as numpy arrays.